# Convert NUMERIC to VARCHAR using sequelize model

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js, numeric

I have this NUMERIC(20) field on mssql and I'm trying do read it as a data type string to get the full number because int limits on javascript

```
code: {
 type: DataTypes.STRING
}
```

But the returned value is a truncated INT

```
[ {code: 4216113112911594000 } ]
```

No matter what kind of data type choose it'll return as truncated int

The original values is `4216113112911594192`. This is a java UUID

How can a convert this value to using `model.findAll()`

This is a already created table for another application and I'm trying to read it using sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go :**

```
code: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER , // <------ keep is as DB's datatype
    get() { // <------ Use getter method to modify the output of query
        return this.getDataValue('code').toString();
    }
}
```

---

**I think this might help you**

```
model.findOne({
    attributes: [[db.sequelize.literal('cast(`code` as varchar)'), 'code_string']] ,
    where : { id : YOUR_ID }
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data); // <------ Check your output here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer now its returning a string but the value stilll trucated           
`[ { code: '4216113112911594000'}]`

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully understood what you are trying to achieve.

Nor my code is tested.

Idea 1 : convert into float.

Idea 2 : Append any string alphabet to originial int value before sending to javascript.

The original values is `4216113112911594192`. 
So the string become `'A'+'4216113112911594192'='A4216113112911594192'`

Now you can play with `'A4216113112911594192'`

There are many javascript library to support big integer.
[BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)

Comment: The problem is that I always get a trucanted int inside the get function on my model

Answer (score 0):

This worked for postgres (thanks [Bessonov](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/78#issuecomment-514638330) & [vitaly-t](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/78#issuecomment-538632724)!)

Just add this before you initialize sequelize

```js
import pg from 'pg'

// Parse bigints and bigint arrays
pg.types.setTypeParser(20, BigInt) // Type Id 20 = BIGINT | BIGSERIAL
const parseBigIntArray = pg.types.getTypeParser(1016) // 1016 = Type Id for arrays of BigInt values
pg.types.setTypeParser(1016, (a) => parseBigIntArray(a).map(BigInt))
```

A little background:
I didn't want Sequelize to parse bigint columns as strings, so I added `pg.defaults.parseInt8 = true`. That made pg start parsing bigints as regular numbers, but it truncated numbers that were too big. I ended up going with the above solution.